# Need to remove space in the output

Tags: java, string, file

> when i run this with a file whose contents are :

```
       S O R T E X A M P L E
       H e l l o 
       W o r l D
```

> It prints with space between 1st and 2nd line like this :

```
         s o r t e x a m p l e

         h e l l o 
         w o r l d
```

> how do i remove the space?
>
> here is the code

```
import java.util.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        //if(args.length==0){
            //return;}
        List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();
        FileReader text = new FileReader(args[0]);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(text);


        try {
            String Line = br.readLine();
        while(Line!=null){
            result.add(Line.toLowerCase());     //apply method on individual Lines here!!
            Line = br.readLine();
        }}
        finally{br.close();}

        for(int i =0;i<result.size();i++){
            System.out.println(result.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not printing any extra empty lines for me, why? I just copy pasted your code.

Comment: Are you working on Linux, Mac or Windows? Was the file created on Windows?

Comment: Is there a chance the first line in your file may contain a character \n that is not treated as an actual newline character because you open it on Windows?

Comment: you have space in input so you are seeing it in output.

Comment: i dont know what was wrong, there was no space in my input file, but i created new file with same contents and it runs perfect without any space , dont know what was that !! i double checked there was no space in the first input file.

Comment: To be removed if it cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having NewLine Character in your file at the end of first line `\n`

See this Example

```
  List<String> line=new LinkedList<>();
                line.add("abn\n");  // You might be having a new Line character 
                line.add("bce");
                line.add("def");
                for(String s:line){
                    System.out.println(s);
                 }
```

So Your Output contains is like this

```
abn

bce
def
```

Comment: no nothing like that, just plain string as i have mentioned above

Comment: @ajsum0  what OS are you using? linux, windows, mac?

Comment: @Anil Windows8.1 64bit  why?what does this have to do with it?

Comment: @Anil i was using the same file for multiple java programs, maybe that had to do something with it, i am not sure though.

Comment: @ajsum0 anyway it is working ok right.  I was just wondering how are you passing arguments, is it command line or using BlueJ kind of stuff.

Comment: @Anil Ok, i am using Eclipse so using the run configuration>Arguments>file.txt to pass the argument. can't do in command line.